# Instantiating the same scala class from main

Tags: scala

In Java I usually do something like:

```
class Hello {
    public Hello() {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Hello();
    }
}
```

How do I do something similar in Scala? I start off with Hello being a Scala object like so:

```
object Hello {

    // constructor goes here

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        println("hello") // new Hello() would go here
    }
}
```

but I can't instantiate that. If I change I change the object keyword to class then the scala compiler complains i.e.

```
class Hello {

    println("hello")

    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        new Hello()
    }
}
```

I know I'm probably on completely the wrong track here but I'd like to be put out of my misery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you understand what a Scala `object` is. It is actually the equivalent of a Java singleton, where an anonymous class is created and instantiated in place.

If you would recompile the code to Java in this scenario:

```
object Hello {}
```

It would get something like:

```
public class Hello$ {
  public static Hello$ $MODULE = new Hello$()
}
```

This is already a singleton, an equivalent of a `val`. You can even do:

```
val x = Hello; // x will be of type Hello.type
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I understand that an object is equivalent to a Java singleton I was just wondering what the common way of starting a Scala application is. Do you start off with an object and then use that to instantiate a bunch of other scala classes in separate files?

Comment: Isn't the point of extending `App` to avoid having to declare a `main`? http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.App

Comment: Actually, you don't need to extend `App` in order to have a startable program; it's sufficient to simply define the `main` method of any `object`. (Important to keep in mind: If that object has a companion `class` or `trait`, using it as the main class won't work.) However, if you extend the `App` trait, you can simply just write your code into the body of the `object`, without the need to define any method at all. Like this `object Example extends App { println("Yay, it works!") }`

Answer (score 2):

Usually for this in Scala i use objects representing the application:

```
object Hello extends App {
    println("hello")
}
```